# Trouble with Key Bindings

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I am creating a Pong clone, and I am trying to use KeyBindings. This works:

```
getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F2"),"leftup");
        getActionMap().put("leftup", new AbstractAction() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -7625435800213244316L;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Yay");
            }
        });
```

But not this:

```
getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, Event.ACTION_EVENT),"leftup");
        getActionMap().put("leftup", new AbstractAction() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -7625435800213244316L;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Yay");
            }
        });
```

Comment: You haven't stated what you are trying to do, only that the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Java docs, there's no overload of `getKeyStroke` that fits KeyEvent, Event.

Pretty sure

```
getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, Event.ACTION_EVENT),"leftup");
```

should be

```
getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W),"leftup");
```

Comment: It returns an int, not a KeyEvent.

Comment: Ah, I see. In which case, the docs state that the second parameter should be a modifier mask, not an event type. Set it to 0 as per http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke%28int,%20int%29